# Sort a cell array of strings alphabetically by last name

Tags: regex, matlab, sorting, names

In Matlab, I have a cell array like:

```
names = {
    'John Doe',
    'Jane Watkins',
    'Jeremy Jason Taylor',
    'Roger Adrian'
    }
```

I would like to sort these such that the **last names** appear in alphabetical order. In my example, it would come out being:

```
names_sorted = {
    'Roger Adrian',
    'John Doe',
    'Jeremy Jason Taylor',
    'Jane Watkins'
    }
```

I know of inelegant ways of doing this. For instance, I could tokenize at space, make a separate `last_names` cell array, sort that, and apply the indexing to my original array.

My question is, is there a better way?

Because someone is sure to come up with that list of assumptions you can't make with regards to people names in a database, let me assure you that all my names are either `"FIRST MIDDLE LAST"` or `"FIRST LAST"`. I checked.

Comment: as far as I know, you will have to sort a secondary array and apply the indexing to the original one, the only sort functions in matlab that I know don't let you specify a sorting condition... but now you got me curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all first names had the same length, then you would be able to use `sortrows`, but in your case, that would require padding and modifying your array, anyway, so that you're better off converting it into `"LAST FIRST MIDDLE"` before applying `sort`. Fortunately, there's a simple regular expression for that:

```
names = {'John Doe';'Roger Adrian';'John Fitzgerald Kennedy'};
names_rearranged = regexprep(names,'(.*) (\w*)$','$2 $1')
names_rearranged = 
    'Doe John'
    'Adrian Roger'
    'Kennedy John Fitzgerald'

[names_rearranged_sorted, idx_sorted] = sort(names_rearranged);

names_sorted = names(idx_sorted)
names_sorted = 
    'Roger Adrian'
    'John Doe'
    'John Fitzgerald Kennedy'
```